# Bing News Search from 2014 to 2016

Tags: azure, bing-api

Is it possible to get all news for a specific request from 2014 to 2016?
This is because when I do my request, i only get the 10 last results.
Is there a way to select the period you want the news for?

This would be amazing.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from the [Bing News Search API v7 Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cognitiveservices/bing-news-api-v7-reference):

> **Freshness**
>   Filter news articles by the following age values:
>
> - Day—Return news articles that Bing discovered within the last 24 hours
> - Week—Return news articles that Bing discovered within the last 7 days
> - Month—Return news articles that Bing discovered within the last 30 days

This is the only filter on something that resembles date. In short: no, the API does not support filtering on a specific period.

Looking at the [Cognitive Services News Search API - v7](https://dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/e5e22123c5d24f1081f63af1548defa1/operations/56b449fbcf5ff81038d15cdf) there's no filtering on date whatsoever.

The API you're calling is a relevant news service, not a news archive.